# PySide RegExp matching from list

Tags: python, regex, pyqt, pyside

Hello I am writing a simple text editor in PySide and I want to colour code certain ketwords.  This is how I match a comment.

```
comment    = QtCore.QRegExp(r'\(\*(.*)?')
```

to match a single keyword

```
keyword    = QtCore.QRegExp(r'/action/')
```

How would I be able to match from a list like this:

```
reserved_words = ["if", "else", "elseif", "while"]
keywords = QtCore.QRegExp(r'/match_the_reserced_kewords_here/')
```

Answer (score 0):

For matching a single keyword (or many), you need to define what characters are allowed in a keyword. Otherwise, you will match `action` in `reaction`, which might not be what you want.

The correct way to match a single keyword is to assert word boundary `\b` before and after the word.

```
r'/\baction\b/'
```

To match any of the keywords, you need to construct the regex with alternation `|` in between the words:

```
r'/\b(' + r'|'.join(reserved_words) + r')\b/'
```

**This solution assumes the keyword doesn't contain any meta characters in regex**, such as `.`, `?`, `*`, `+`, `[`, `]`, `(`, `)`, `{`, `}`, `\`, `^`, `$`, `|`.

The problem is not as simple as escaping the meta characters, since there is also the word boundary. However, I guess that reserved keyword only consists of English alphabet characters; there shouldn't be any problem if that is the case.

Comment: thank you :) would you know how to not match the keywords if there are in a comment?

Comment: @user1976336: I don't know. You should take a look at existing code highlighting library to see how they do it.